# AVAnimator mvid conversion

Tags: ios, apng

Is there no way to play an `apng` file directly in iOS?

I tried `AVAnimator`, but its solution is to convert the `apng` file to `mvid` and then play it frame-by-frame and then to reduce file storage space, it would compress the `mvid` file into `7z`.

So, my question is,

1. Am I right about what `AVAnimator` does?
2. Is there any other solution apart from `AVAnimator` for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is how decompression of the apng file format is implemented, except that there is no 7z decompression. Decompression is from .apng which is basically the same format as .png with zlib compression. That compressed format is decoded to raw image data and then the animation is displayed frame by frame. This is the only way it can be implemented on a mobile client. There is no other solution for playback of apng in an iOS app, I looked at everything that was available before I implemented AVAnimator's APNG support.