# Huge memory usage when displaying gifs Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, memory, gif

I am making an app that is displaying gifs in a UIImageView loading the gif from parse. The issue I stumble upon is whenever I load a Gif it uses about 20 mb of memory, and it this memory is not allocated when I perform a segue. I remove the image itself from the UIImageView, but it still doesnt free the memory.

This is the code I use to show the gif:

```
extension UIImage {

public class func gifWithData(data: NSData) -> UIImage? {
    guard let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data, nil) else {
        print("SwiftGif: Source for the image does not exist")
        return nil
    }
    return UIImage.animatedImageWithSource(source)
}

public class func gifWithName(name: String) -> UIImage? {
    guard let bundleURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(name, withExtension: "gif") else {
        print("SwiftGif: This image named \"\(name)\" does not exist")
        return nil
    }
    guard let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: bundleURL) else {
        print("SwiftGif: Cannot turn image named \"\(name)\" into NSData")
        return nil
    }
    return gifWithData(imageData)
}

class func delayForImageAtIndex(index: Int, source: CGImageSource!) -> Double {
    var delay = 0.1

    // Get dictionaries
    let cfProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, index, nil)
    let gifProperties: CFDictionaryRef = unsafeBitCast(
        CFDictionaryGetValue(cfProperties,
            unsafeAddressOf(kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary)),
        CFDictionary.self)

    // Get delay time
    var delayObject: AnyObject = unsafeBitCast(
        CFDictionaryGetValue(gifProperties,
            unsafeAddressOf(kCGImagePropertyGIFUnclampedDelayTime)),
        AnyObject.self)
    if delayObject.doubleValue == 0 {
        delayObject = unsafeBitCast(CFDictionaryGetValue(gifProperties,
            unsafeAddressOf(kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime)), AnyObject.self)
    }

    delay = delayObject as! Double

    if delay < 0.1 {
        delay = 0.1 // Make sure they're not too fast
    }

    return delay
}

class func gcdForPair(var a: Int?, var _ b: Int?) -> Int {
    // Check if one of them is nil
    if b == nil || a == nil {
        if b != nil {
            return b!
        } else if a != nil {
            return a!
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    // Swap for modulo
    if a < b {
        let c = a
        a = b
        b = c
    }

    // Get greatest common divisor
    var rest: Int
    while true {
        rest = a! % b!

        if rest == 0 {
            return b! // Found it
        } else {
            a = b
            b = rest
        }
    }
}

class func gcdForArray(array: Array<Int>) -> Int {
    if array.isEmpty {
        return 1
    }

    var gcd = array[0]

    for val in array {
        gcd = UIImage.gcdForPair(val, gcd)
    }

    return gcd
}

class func animatedImageWithSource(source: CGImageSource) -> UIImage? {
    let count = CGImageSourceGetCount(source)
    var images = [CGImageRef]()
    var delays = [Int]()

    // Fill arrays
    for i in 0..<count {
        // Add image
        if let image = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, i, nil) {
            images.append(image)
        }

        // At it's delay in cs
        let delaySeconds = UIImage.delayForImageAtIndex(Int(i),
            source: source)
        delays.append(Int(delaySeconds * 1000.0)) // Seconds to ms
    }

    // Calculate full duration
    let duration: Int = {
        var sum = 0

        for val: Int in delays {
            sum += val
        }

        return sum
        }()

    // Get frames
    let gcd = gcdForArray(delays)
    var frames = [UIImage]()

    var frame: UIImage
    var frameCount: Int
    for i in 0..<count {
        frame = UIImage(CGImage: images[Int(i)])
        frameCount = Int(delays[Int(i)] / gcd)

        for _ in 0..<frameCount {
            frames.append(frame)
        }
    }

    // Heyhey
    let animation = UIImage.animatedImageWithImages(frames,
        duration: Double(duration) / 1000.0)

    return animation
}

class func FinalFrame(source: CGImageSource) -> UIImage? {
    let count = CGImageSourceGetCount(source)
    var images = [CGImageRef]()
    var delays = [Int]()
    var finalFrame = UIImage()

    // Fill arrays
    for i in 0..<count {
        // Add image
        if let image = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, i, nil) {
            images.append(image)
        }

        // At it's delay in cs
        let delaySeconds = UIImage.delayForImageAtIndex(Int(i),
            source: source)
        delays.append(Int(delaySeconds * 1000.0)) // Seconds to ms
    }

    // Get frames
    let gcd = gcdForArray(delays)
    var frames = [UIImage]()

    var frame: UIImage
    var frameCount: Int
    for i in 0..<count {
        frame = UIImage(CGImage: images[Int(i)])
        frameCount = Int(delays[Int(i)] / gcd)

        for _ in 0..<frameCount {
            frames.append(frame)
        }
    }
    finalFrame = frames[frames.count-1]

    return finalFrame
}
}
```

Could this be the reason why I get the memory issues?
Appreciate any help!

Comment: Both GIF and APNG can be handled with low memory reqs like so: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25478854/763355

Answer (score 0):

I decided to add full code for memory saving, if you are using GIF files, modify UIImage scale method (Found it here, an Stackoverflow). As said GangstaGraham in SD Image exist method sd_animatedImageByScalingAndCroppingToSize

```
@interface UIImage (Scaling)

-(UIImage *)imageByScalingProportionallyToSize:(CGSize)targetSize;
-(UIImage*) croppedImageWithRect: (CGRect) rect;

@end

@implementation UIImage (Scaling)

- (UIImage *)imageByScalingProportionallyToSize:(CGSize)targetSize {

    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0) {
            targetSize.height *= 2.0f;
            targetSize.width *= 2.0f;
        }
    }

    NSUInteger width = targetSize.width;
    NSUInteger height = targetSize.height;
    UIImage *newImage = [self resizedImageWithMinimumSize: CGSizeMake (width, height)];
    return [newImage croppedImageWithRect: CGRectMake ((newImage.size.width - width) / 2, (newImage.size.height - height) / 2, width, height)];
}

-(CGImageRef)CGImageWithCorrectOrientation
{
    if (self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
        //retaining because caller expects to own the reference
        CGImageRetain([self CGImage]);
        return [self CGImage];
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, 90 * M_PI/180);
    } else if (self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, -90 * M_PI/180);
    } else if (self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, 180 * M_PI/180);
    }

    [self drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

    CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return cgImage;
}

-(UIImage*)resizedImageWithMinimumSize:(CGSize)size
{
    CGImageRef imgRef = [self CGImageWithCorrectOrientation];
    CGFloat original_width  = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
    CGFloat original_height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);
    CGFloat width_ratio = size.width / original_width;
    CGFloat height_ratio = size.height / original_height;
    CGFloat scale_ratio = width_ratio > height_ratio ? width_ratio : height_ratio;
    CGImageRelease(imgRef);
    return [self drawImageInBounds: CGRectMake(0, 0, round(original_width * scale_ratio), round(original_height * scale_ratio))];
}

-(UIImage*)drawImageInBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);
    [self drawInRect: bounds];
    UIImage *resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resizedImage;
}

-(UIImage*)croppedImageWithRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(-rect.origin.x, -rect.origin.y, self.size.width, self.size.height);
    CGContextClipToRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height));
    [self drawInRect:drawRect];
    UIImage* subImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return subImage;
}

-(UIImage *) resizableImageWithCapInsets2: (UIEdgeInsets) inset
{
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:)])
    {
        return [self resizableImageWithCapInsets:inset resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
    }
    else
    {
        float left = (self.size.width-2)/2;//The middle points rarely vary anyway
        float top = (self.size.height-2)/2;
        return [self stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:left topCapHeight:top];
    }
}

@end
```

And UIImageView:

```
#import <SDWebImage/SDImageCache.h>

@implementation UIImageView (Scaling)

-(void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL*)url scaleToSize:(BOOL)scale
{
    if(url.absoluteString.length < 10) return;
    if(!scale){
        [self setImageWithURL:url];
        return;
    }
    __block UIImageView* selfimg = self;
    __block NSString* prevKey = SPRINTF(@"%@_%ix%i", url.absoluteString, (int)self.frame.size.width, (int)self.frame.size.height);
    __block UIImage* prevImage = nil;

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^ {

        prevImage = [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] imageFromDiskCacheForKey:prevKey];
        if(prevImage){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
                [self setImage:prevImage];
            });
        }else{

            [[SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader] downloadImageWithURL:url options:SDWebImageDownloaderFILOQueueMode progress:nil completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished) {
                if(error){
                    [selfimg setImageWithURL:url scaleToSize:scale];
                }else{
                    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
                    dispatch_async(queue, ^ {
                        prevImage = [image imageByScalingProportionallyToSize:self.frame.size];
                        if(finished)
                            [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] storeImage:prevImage forKey:prevKey];
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
                            [self setImage:prevImage];
                        });
                    });
                }
            }];
        }
    });

    return;
}

-(void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder scaleToSize:(BOOL)scale
{
    [self setImage:placeholder];
    [self setImageWithURL:url scaleToSize:scale];
}


@end
```